# Add a header for a context menu that the user cannot select

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I am trying to add a header to a context menu.  The xaml below almost does what I need.  The problem is that the user can select the TextBlock and if they click the Textblock the menu vanishes.  (If the user clicks the Separator the menu remains.)  So basically I want the TextBlock not to be highlighted if the user moves their mouse over it and I also don't want the menu to vanish if the user clicks the TextBlock.

```
<TextBlock.ContextMenu>
    <ContextMenu>
        <TextBlock Text="Test!!!" />
        <Separator></Separator>
        <MenuItem Header="menu item1" />
        <MenuItem Header="menu item2" />
    </ContextMenu>
</TextBlock.ContextMenu>
```

Comment: IsHitTestVisible=false should make it so you can not click it. Although, I believe you'd still be able to use the keyboard to select it. Maybe Focusable=False?

Comment: What are you actually trying to achieve? What is your overriding goal?

Comment: I want a header that is some text that the user can't highlight or select with a mouse.  And if they click on it it won't cause the menu to vanish.  The Focusable is set to false by default. The IsHitTestVisile= false didn't do anything noticeable.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use a custom template on your separator to achieve what you want

```
<TextBlock.ContextMenu>
    <ContextMenu>
        <Separator>
            <Separator.Template>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="Separator">
                    <StackPanel>
                        <TextBlock Text="Test!!!" />
                        <Separator/>
                    </StackPanel>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Separator.Template>
        </Separator>
        <MenuItem Header="menu item1" />
        <MenuItem Header="menu item2" />
    </ContextMenu>
</TextBlock.ContextMenu>
```

This way the text is not responding to clicks or hovers and keeps the menu open, plus you can reuse if you turn the template into a ressource.

Comment: Hi thanks for your reply.  This works as well.  Hmmm now I'm gonna have to choose between your answer and ethicallogics.

Comment: This is a nice solution, but the "inner" separator gets drawn as a full-width black line, not in the normal style for separators inside context menus.  But you can fix that by using `<Separator Style="{StaticResource {x:Static MenuItem.SeparatorStyleKey}}" />` instead.  You'll also want to use at least `Margin="32,0,8,0"` on the TextBlock.

Answer (score 2):

If you just want to add some space above the `Separator` in your `ContextMenu`, then it is customary to use the `Margin` property. As there are four input values, we just need to set only the 'up' value. Try this:

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding SomeTextField}">
    <TextBlock.ContextMenu>
        <ContextMenu>
            <Separator Margin="0,25,0,0"></Separator>
            <MenuItem Header="menu item1" />
            <MenuItem Header="menu item2" />
        </ContextMenu>
    </TextBlock.ContextMenu>
</TextBlock>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type ContextMenu}">
        <Setter Property="SnapsToDevicePixels" Value="True" />
        <Setter Property="OverridesDefaultStyle" Value="True" />
        <Setter Property="Grid.IsSharedSizeScope" Value="true" />
        <Setter Property="HasDropShadow" Value="True" />
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ContextMenu}">
                    <Border x:Name="Border"  Background="White"  BorderThickness="1" BorderBrush="Gray">
                        <StackPanel>
                            <TextBlock Text="Test!!!!"/>
                            <Separator></Separator>
                        <StackPanel 
                            IsItemsHost="True"
                            KeyboardNavigation.DirectionalNavigation="Cycle" />
                        </StackPanel>
                    </Border>
                    <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                        <Trigger Property="HasDropShadow" Value="true">
                            <Setter TargetName="Border" Property="Padding" Value="0,3,0,3" />
                            <Setter TargetName="Border" Property="CornerRadius" Value="4" />
                        </Trigger>
                    </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
```